# Maven repository server for independent teams

Tags: maven, nexus, artifactory

We are looking into setting up a local maven repository server at our institute. We have several teams that are completely independent and therefore should not have write access to each others artifacts.

Ideally we would like a similar permission concept as e.g. Gitlab, where every user can create a project (or in this case repository) and give permissions to it, but not have write access to any other repositories.

I tried out Artifactory and Nexus, but as far as I could tell, giving permissions to a group for a specific project includes manual work for a user with full admin rights, namely creating that repository.

Is there a freely available maven repository server, that allows creation and administration of repositories by users without giving them access to other repositories? If not, is there one, that can restrict write access for an artifact to the person who first deployed it?

Even better if Artifactory or Nexus can in fact do something like that and I just missed it.

Comment: If you are using the administrative account that's the way it is. Apart from that only a CI server should have the permission to store artifacts into a repository manager. furthermore the artifacts are separated by groupId/artifactId/version...so I don't see the real problem...And yes you can make such complicated setup to have separated permissions for groupId's in Nexus 2 and also Nexus 3 but I wouldn't recommend it based on the amount of administrative work in relationship to the advantages you get...Can you describe what the real problem is?

Comment: @khmarbaise I understand, that this is the usual setup in a company, but we are a university institute, the different groups are more independent than teams in the same compan. Also there is a lot of small projects with changing students, allowing only the CI publishing would only shift our permission problem to the CI servers. But at least that would enable each group to manage their permissions instead of one central place doing it, so we may consider it.

Comment: I would recommend to use Nexus 3 where you can use scripts to setup permissions/different repositories see for example here: http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2017/10/02/nexus-scripted-setup/

Answer (score 0):

You can create an arbitrary number of repositories in one Nexus 2.x (professional) server. Then you can set up different user accounts with different writing rights, e.g. you can create a `projectA` repository and define a `projectAuser` which has writing rights only for this particular repository.

I guess this is possible in Artifactory and Nexus 3 as well, but I do not have experience.

Answer (score 0):

In Artifactory you have many options, I recommend you:

- Create a virtual maven repository with permissions for a group of users.
- Configure the settings.xml of this group of users with this virtual repository.
- Create remote repositories to access to Github or any other websites.
- Add these remote repositories to the virtual repository.
- Create local repositories if you need and add to the virtual repository.

Do this with every group of users that you want and you will have independent artifacts and repositories.

Comment: I understand, that I can create those separate groups manually as admin. I hoped for a "everybody can create new groupIds, but can not publish to the ones another one created first" kind of solution, but seeing that even the central repository on maven.org seems to require an admin to create a new groupId, that seems to be the only way